# The man hoping to escape

Tags: grammar

These sentences are from Oxford Style Guide. They are given as restrictive and non-restrictive clauses. How does the speaker  choose which clause he wants to use restrictive or non-restrictive?
I understand this part "hoping to escape" in the the second sentence to be the defining part which means "the man who was hoping to escape" as in "not the other man" but the one who was was hoping to escape mingled with the crowd. While in the first sentence the main message of the sentence is that the man mingled with the crowd. Do I understand correctly? What exactly defines the main message in the first sentence is defined by the context, isn't it? By what the speaker wants to express which is based on the situation or context.

1. "The man, hoping to escape, mingled with the crowd."
2. "The man hoping to escape mingled with the crowd."

Comment: (1) could be written as "Hoping to escape, the man mingled with the crowd" (where we already know which man is being referred to).

Comment: In both cases *the main message of the sentence is that the man mingled with the crowd*. The difference is the *first* one tells us that the ***reason*** he did this was in hopes of escaping, whereas the second one specifically identifies the subject as ***that*** man (the one who hoped to escape, not some other man). Note that we infer "reason" there because of the exact nature of the non-restrictive clause. It could just as well be *The man, **sweating with fear,** mingled with the crowd*, in which case it's ***describing*** his state rather than "explaining" his actions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, and  what is going to be used the restrictive or non-restrictive clause depends on the speaker and the situation, on what I want my sentence to express.  Right? I can use it as a non-restrictive and express the reason he did it was in hopes of escaping, or I can use it as a restrictive to mean *that* man not some other man hoped to escape.

Comment: Approximately, yes. But note that *neither* of your examples is particularly idiomatic. Because ***hoping to escape*** is such an "unusual" way to identify a specific person as a *restrictive* clause, a native speaker might preface it by pronoun+verb ***who was*** (after a significant pause) to make sure the audience could easily parse the words as they were being heard / read. And as a *non-restrictive* clause (just giving more info about the man or his action), it would be much easier to parse if you put it ***before or after the main statement***, rather than immediately after the subject.

Comment: ...sorry - got some things mixed up in that long comment. Bottom line is you shouldn't rely too heavily on people noticing your commas in text, or pauses in speech, to unambiguously distinguish between restrictive and non-restrictive clauses. If there seems to be scope for confusion, just rephrase.

Comment: The examples aren't mine. They are from "Oxford Style Guide".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, In the same way "The man who was carrying a  child was my father."  Means the one carrying a child was my father. Not some other man was carrying a child. But  "The man, who was carrying a child, was my father." Means the one I am talking about is my father."  The fact that he's carrying a child is not important for some reason. Right?